# Date conversion using R package

Tags: r, date-conversion

I have date column like below format. I want to convert this to yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
|Date_Col|
----------
|14/10/2017 10:58|
|30/09/2017 23:15|
|14/05/2016 21:10|
|16/06/2018 22:10|
|07/06/2016 13:05|
|19/02/2017 13:16|
```

When I use `as.Date(df$Date_Col)`, it returns *"0014-10-20" "0030-09-20" "0014-05-20" "0016-06-20" "0007-06-20" "0019-02-20"*

If I use `as.Date(df$Date_Col, "%m/%d/%Y")`, it gives *NA   NA  NA   NA   "2016-07-06" NA*

If I use `library(lubridate)` and `mdy(df$Date_Col)`, it gives *NA NA NA NA NA NA* Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Any suggestion how to convert this column to yyyy-mm-dd format?

Thanking advance for your time.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please provide a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is unclear what your input data is. Are these strings or datetime-objects?

Comment: try "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime for formats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to a solution with either Base R or the `lubridate` package is to include hour and minute specifications into the `format=` argument on the date conversion function to tell R how to parse the time information in the input text strings.

One way to convert the values in the original post is with the `as.POSIXlt()` function, and the following format syntax. We can use the `format()` function to print the resulting object in the `%Y-%m-%d` format.

```
format(as.POSIXlt("14/10/2017 10:58",format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

...and the output:

```
> format(as.POSIXlt("14/10/2017 10:58",format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-10-14"
```

`as.Date()` also works as long as one uses the `format=` argument and includes the `%H:%M` content:

```
format(as.Date("14/10/2017 10:58",format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")

> format(as.Date("14/10/2017 10:58",format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-10-14"
```

With the `lubridate` package, we can use `as_date()`.

```
library(lubridate)
format(as_date(df$Date,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")

> format(as_date(df$Date,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-10-14" "2017-09-30" "2016-05-14" "2018-06-16" "2016-06-07" "2017-02-19"
```

A reproducible example with the list of dates from the original post looks like this.

```
textData <- "Date
14/10/2017 10:58 
30/09/2017 23:15 
14/05/2016 21:10 
16/06/2018 22:10 
07/06/2016 13:05 
19/02/2017 13:16"

df <- read.csv(text=textData,header=TRUE,colClasses = "character")

format(as.Date(df$Date,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

...and the output:

```
> format(as.Date(df$Date,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-10-14" "2017-09-30" "2016-05-14" "2018-06-16" "2016-06-07" "2017-02-19"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dmy_hm` from `lubridate` to convert data to date-time.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm(df$Date_Col)

#[1] "2017-10-14 10:58:00 UTC" "2017-09-30 23:15:00 UTC"
#[3] "2016-05-14 21:10:00 UTC" "2018-06-16 22:10:00 UTC"
#[5] "2016-06-07 13:05:00 UTC" "2017-02-19 13:16:00 UTC"
```

If you need only dates add `as.Date` to above output.

```
as.Date(dmy_hm(df$Date_Col))
#[1]"2017-10-14" "2017-09-30" "2016-05-14" "2018-06-16" "2016-06-07" "2017-02-19"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date_Col = c("14/10/2017 10:58", "30/09/2017 23:15", 
"14/05/2016 21:10", "16/06/2018 22:10", "07/06/2016 13:05", "19/02/2017 13:16")),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```